# windowsでrails newができない：Could not find gem 'rails (~> 6.1.3, >= 6.1.3.1)' in rubygems repository

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows

railsをインストールした後にnewでフォルダをつくる際にこのようなエラーがでてしまいます。どのようにしたら解決しますか。

```
Could not find gem 'rails (~> 6.1.3, >= 6.1.3.1)' in rubygems repository 
https://rubygems.org/ or installed locally. 
The source does not contain any versions
of 'rails' Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sudoを使ってBandleをインストールしていたりしませんか？
その場合、rootが所有者になってしまいます。

```
sudo chown -R ユーザー名:staff /Users/ユーザー名.rbenv
```

を実行してみてください。

Comment: 解決しました。ありがとうございます。